# In what manner(or way) the data is being readed from the InputStream?

Tags: java, sockets, io, datainputstream, dataoutputstream

Client:

```
int[] handshake_payload = {0x00,0x04,0x12A,0x01,0x06,0x135959}; //an array of hex values to be sent
        for(int n:handshake_payload)
          dataOutputStream.write(n);
        dataOutputStream.flush();
```

Server:

```
int tag = dataInputStream.readUnsignedByte();
System.out.println("Tag:"+String.format("%02X", tag)); //prints Tag:00; this is fine
int len = dataInputStream.readUnsignedShort();
System.out.println("Len:"+String.format("%02X", len)); //prints Len: 42A , why not 412A (even when 412A
                                                       //fits in 16 bits of readUnsignedShort())
int val = dataInputStream.read();
System.out.println("Val:"+String.format("%02X", val)); //prints Val:01; fine
int valb = dataInputStream.readUnsignedByte();
System.out.println(String.format("%02X", valb)); //prints 06; fine
int vals = dataInputStream.readUnsignedByte();
System.out.println(String.format("%02X", vals)); // prints 59 , how do I read this in order to get the complete value 135959 , tried with readInt but throws EOFException, since end of stream reached before reading 4 bytes
```

Why is the last readUnsignedByte() returning 59 , & not 13 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is on the writing end rather than the reading end.

> Why is the last `readUnsignedByte()` returning 59 , & not 13 ?

Because that is what was actually written.  The `write(int b)` method is [specified](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#write(int)) as follows:

> *"Writes the specified byte **(the low eight bits of the argument `b`)** to the underlying output stream."*

So `write(0x135959)` writes one byte: `0x59`.

If you want to write the `int` as 4 bytes, use the `writeInt(int)` method instead.

If you want to write the `int` as 1 to 4 bytes without sending the non-significant leading zero bytes ... there isn't an API call to do that.  You will need to implement it using a loop with some shifting and masking ... or similar.

Comment: Thanks, please put some light on System.out.println("Len:"+String.format("%02X", len)); why is it printing 42A instead of 412A ?

Comment: For the same reason as above.  The bottom 8 bits of `0x12A` are `0x2A`.